# Is it possible to use Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler to scale nodes if number of nodes hit a threshold?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I created an EKS cluster but while deploying pods, I found out that the native AWS CNI only supports a set number of pods because of the IP restrictions on its instances. I don't want to use any third-party plugins because AWS doesn't support them and we won't be able to get their tech support. What happens right now is that as soon as the IP limit is hit for that instance, the scheduler is not able to schedule the pods and the pods go into pending state.

I see there is a cluster autoscaler which can do horizontal scaling.

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler
```

Using a larger instance type with more available IPs is an option but that is not scalable since we will run out of IPs eventually.
Is it possible to set a pod limit for each node in cluster-autoscaler and if that limit is reached, a new instance is spawned. Since each pod uses one secondary IP of the node so that would solve our issue of not having to worry about scaling. Is this a viable option? and also if anybody has faced this and would like to share how they overcame this limitation.

Comment: Which instance type are you using? Personally, I used larger instances that have an acceptable [maximum number of pods](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt). The [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) seems to scale the cluster when there are pods that fail to run because of insufficient resources. So, your use case could work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was testing it with t3.medium instances and was able to deploy auto-scaler and it worked. It scales up and down. The only downside is that it is reactive but I have readiness probes enabled so there is no downtime when new nodes are being added to the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EKS's node group is using auto scaling group for nodes scaling.

You can follow [this workshop](https://eksworkshop.com/scaling/deploy_ca/) as a dedicated example.

Comment: Thanks. I used the helm chart and it worked. Here is the link - https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/cluster-autoscaler